# Java Scanner проблема с чтением

Tags: java

Использую среду NetBeans. Проблема в том что обьект Scanner отказываеться читать строку с файла. Файл в корневой папке и не пустой. Подскажите что не так. Файл точно не пустой, первая строка: read - читать.  Бросает NoSuchElementException.

```
package maindictionary;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainDictionary {
//private Scanner in;
private String line;
private File file;

public MainDictionary(){
    file = new File("Dict.txt");
    line = "";

}

public void read(){
    Scanner in = null;
    try{
        in = new Scanner(new File("Dict.txt"));
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    line = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainDictionary md = new MainDictionary();
        md.read();
    }

}
```

Comment: У вас в файле точно первая строка не пустая? Т.к. вы читаете одну строку всего навсего

Comment: Для проверки читайте не одну строку, а через цикл while с проверкой in.hasNext()

Comment: а в чем именно проявляется отказ? Могу предположить, что кодировка файла отличается от используемой по-умолчанию (`Charset.defaultCharset()`).

Comment: А что хоть говорит компилятор? Я запустил Ваш код, создал Dict.txt и наполнил его - все читается. Единственное что - я указывал абсолютный путь к файлу

Comment: Не переписывайте тему сообщения, делайте дописку upd. Тяжело понять что у Вас тут происходит. И выложите лог компилятора

Answer (score 2):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( file.getAbsoluteFile()));
    try {
        String s;
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
```

Не проще ли?

Comment: Проще конечно, но я пытаюсь разобраться со Scanner

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за участие ответ уже нашел: все оказалось в кодировке файла .txt как только перевел его в UTF - 8 все начало работать.

Comment: Странно. У меня файл был Win1251. Но у вас разрулилось - и это хорошо